# Change global string within a method in python 3

Tags: python, string, methods, definition

I googled my problem but haven't been able to find an answer. My problem is: 
I'm trying to change a string within a method in python 3. I'm trying a little code like this:

```
number_a = 0
number_b = 1

word = 'empty'

def something():
    if number_a > number_b
        word = 'hello'
    else: 
        word = 'goodbye'

something()
print(word)
```

What Python is giving me for output is

```
empty
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions assume variables are local and assigning a value will by default create a new local variable to contain it. The non-local, *global* variable remains unaffected.

This is desirable. Otherwise you'd have to create unique names for everything and always risk accidentally overwriting an important global variable.

You can change this behaviour by explicitly telling Python that it's the global variable that you want to assign a value to. For that, use the `global` keyword to explicitly link the local name to the global variable:

```
def something():
    global word

    if number_a > number_b
        word = 'hello'
    else: 
        word = 'goodbye'
```

Sometimes this is necessary. In your simple example, however, it would probably be better to just return the value and do the assignment outside of the function. That way the function isn't tied to the surrounding namespace:

```
def something(number_a, number_b):
    if number_a > number_b
        return 'hello'
    else: 
        return 'goodbye'

word = something(a, b)
```

Comment: The use of the term 'read-only' is misleading here.. The issue is that the default scope for variables is local unless declared explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was the 'global' keyword I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you aren't modifying the string, you are reassigning a local variable. That variable does not have scope outside the function unless you declare that the name `word` has global binding. So to fix the problem you need to tell the interpreter that you're affecting the global variable inside your function.

```
def something():
  global word
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `word` variable is only shadowing the `word` variable outside of the function. It's a scope problem. If you want to actually change `word` you could use the `global` keyword, but a more pythonic approach would be something like this:

```
number_a = 0
number_b = 1

word = 'empty'

def something():
    if number_a > number_b:
        word = 'hello'
    else: 
        word = 'goodbye'
    return word

word = something()
print(word)
```

One other clarification is that what you have written is a [function and not a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function).

Methods are associated with objects.

A simpler way to write this function would be something more like this:

```
def something():
    return 'hello' if number_a > number_b else return 'goodbye'
```

Then you wouldn't have to shadow the `word` variable at all.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the `global` keyword as word in your function is *local* to that function but that is generally not the way to go, you can return the result and reassign word to the returned value:

```
word = 'empty'

def something():
   return 'hello'if number_a > number_b else  'goodbye'

word = something()
print(word)
```

Another way would be to put the word in a *mutable* structure:

```
word = ['empty']


def something():
    if number_a > number_b:
        word[0] = 'hello'
    else:
        word[0] = 'goodbye'
something()
print(word[0]) -> "goodbye"
```

But really if you want values to change globally like that you should probably use a  class where word is an attribute:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self,word,n1,n2):
        self.word = word
        self.number_a = n1
        self.number_b = n2

    def something(self):
        if self.number_a > self.number_b:
            self.word = 'hello'
        else:
            self.word = 'goodbye'

inst = Foo("empty",0,1)

inst.something()
print(inst.word)
goodbye
```